# Plot Graph in Android Graphview by average the values having same date

Tags: java

im able to receive data and plot the graph in android but i have been facing problem with the values having same dates. eg : date:17, glucose=95 ; date: 17, glucose= 85; date: 18, glucose= 90; i want to average the values having same date. below is the code used for plotting Graph

```
String Dategm = intent.getStringExtra("Date");
    String glucose = intent.getStringExtra("Glucose");
    if (Dategm != null) {
        String[] ss = Dategm.split("~");
        String[] aa = glucose.split("~");

        for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
            x_gm.add(Long.toString(i));
            y_gm.add(aa[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("size::" + x_gm.size());

        StaticLabelsFormatter staticLabelsFormatter3 = new StaticLabelsFormatter(graphView3);
        staticLabelsFormatter3.setHorizontalLabels(ss);
            graphView3.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(staticLabelsFormatter3);

        LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series3 = new LineGraphSeries<>(Gluco());
        graphView3.addSeries(series3);
        series3.setColor(Color.RED);
        series3.setThickness(6);
        series3.setDrawBackground(true);
        series3.setDrawDataPoints(true);
        series3.setDataPointsRadius(7);
    }


    public DataPoint[] Gluco(){
        int n=x_gm.size();     //to find out the no. of data-points
        DataPoint[] values = new DataPoint[n];     //creating an object of type 
    DataPoint[] of size 'n'
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        DataPoint v = newDataPoint(Double.parseDouble(x_gm.get(i)),Double.parseDouble(y_gm.get(i))); 
            values[i] = v;
    }
    return values;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Comment: do you have a question???